# Removing a div (whose id is made with php) with a button using Onclick doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php, html, button

I am trying to make a button remove the div it is located in using onclick . I tried doing so in a few ways (reducing the visibility, using GetElementById, setting the outerHTML to 0,and yet I am still stuck and would appreciate help.

The div I want removed is the one on top whose id is `"Attraction.$numofatr"`

`$numofatr` should be a number.

**HTML Code**

```
<div id = "<?php echo "Attraction.R.$numofatr";?>" class = "attraction">
  <div class = "atr_image">
    <img src="images/oldtown.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class= "atr_container">
    <button class="button1" id = "<?php echo "R.$numofatr";?> " onclick = "Remove(this.id)">Remove Attraction</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
function Remove(elem){
  var Attraction = "Attraction" + document.getElementById(elem);
  elem.parentNode.removeChild( document.getElementById(Attraction));

  //NOTE - I ALSO TRIED OTHER WAYS SUCH AS:
  // document.getElementById(Attraction).outerHTML = "";
  //document.getElementById(Attraction).style.display="none";
}
```

Note: I am still new to stackoverflow as well as web development.

Note 2 : I think `$numofatr` is defined correctly, and the problem lies within the JS command.

Note 3: I changed the button div since I have been told the html id shouldnt be a number. The problem still persists.

Note 4: This is the whole structure. I doubt any divs are missing.

```
<div id="<?php echo "Attraction.R.$numofatr" ; ?>" class="attraction">
  
  <div class="atr_image">
    <img src="images/oldtown.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="atr_container">
    <div class="atr_name">
      <a><?php  echo $name; ?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="atr_region">
      <p><?php   echo $region;?> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="atr_desc">
      <p><?php  echo $desc1; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="atr_time_container">
      <div class="atr_time">
        <p><?php  echo $hours; ?> </p>
      </div>
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <div class="atr_hours">
        <p><?php echo $actual; ?></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="button1" id="<?php echo "R. $numofatr"?> " onclick="Remove(this.id)">Remove Attraction</button>

    <script>
      function Remove(elem) {
        var Attraction = document.getElementById("Attraction" + elem);
        Attraction.remove();
      }
    </script>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Change this
"Attraction." + document.getElementById(elem);
to
"Attraction" + elem;
  And for the remove part, document.getElementById(Attraction).parentNode.removeChild( document.getElementById(Attraction))

Comment: This is not the error, but if you want to write correct htmt, you cannot start an ID with a number

Comment: Or you could just pass `Remove(this.parent.id)` and remove the button id.

Comment: @Timberman (just FYI) if you want to write HTML5, you can (that has removed almost all existing restrictions on ID attributes) - _selecting_ those elements via CSS selectors will need additional escaping in such cases though, so it is not that recommendable to begin with.

Comment: You have an unclosed `div` right above your button element BTW.

Comment: You should edit the question to show your actual html structure. Right now it's uncertain.

Comment: @El_Vanja The question has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having seen your updated HTML it appears you are declaring the `Remove()` function within every `Attraction` block. This being the case you can simply pass an anonymous function to the `onclick` which receives the node to remove as a closure.

```
onclick="(node => node.remove())(this.closest('.attraction'))"
```

```html
<div id="Attraction1" class="attraction">
  <div class="atr_image">
    <img src="images/oldtown.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="atr_container">
    <button class="button1" onclick="(node => node.remove())(this.closest('.attraction'))">Remove Attraction</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you always want to remove the parent of the button as you say, you can simply pass the `parentNode` to `Remove()` without having to ever query the DOM.

```
onclick="Remove(this.parentNode)"
```

```js
function Remove(node) {
  node.remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="Attraction1" class="attraction">
  <div class="atr_image">
    <img src="images/oldtown.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="atr_container"></div>
  <button class="button1" onclick="Remove(this.parentNode)">Remove Attraction</button>
</div>
```

---

If you are instead wrapping the button in the `atr_container` div you can use `.closest()` to pass the closest ancestor with the relevant class.

```
onclick="Remove(this.closest('.attraction'))"
```

```js
function Remove(node) {
  node.remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="Attraction1" class="attraction">
  <div class="atr_image">
    <img src="images/oldtown.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="atr_container">
    <button class="button1" onclick="Remove(this.closest('.attraction'))">Remove Attraction</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But wont this remove the atr_container instead? I need to remove the div called "Attraction1". Thank you anyway

Comment: you are missing a `div` closing tag so it is hard to tell your intended structure.

Comment: This is not the whole structure, I can post the whole structure i just thought it wasnt relevant

Comment: Thank you so much :D your solution helped me fix the issue

Comment: I used .closest

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id = "<?php echo "Attraction.$numofatr";?>" class = "attraction">

<div class = "atr_image"><img src="images/oldtown.jpg" alt=""></div>

<div class= "atr_container">



<button class="button1" id = "<?php echo "$numofatr";?> " onclick = "Remove(this.id)">Remove Attraction</button>

</div>
```

And your JS can looks like this:

```
function Remove(elem){
    var Attraction = document.getElementById("Attraction"+elem);
    Attraction.remove();
}
```

Here is a simple test on JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rv5dby92/

Comment: I like the way you simplified the `Remove` function. I'd just like to point out it could be further simplified by calling `document.getElementById("Attraction"+elem).remove()`, without creating a variable.

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesnt seem to work. maybe the problem lies elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the div on `<div id = "<?php echo "Attraction.$numofatr";?>" class = "attraction">`

```
function Remove(elem){
    document.getElementById('Attraction'+elem).remove();
}
```

**Please note**, you are using the id attribute with numeric values. Maybe this is not valid by HTML standards

Your code contain `elem`.`parentNode`.`removeChild` it sound like go to parent of element, and back to child.
For removeChild
Try from w3schools.com tutorial:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_removechild.asp

Hope you solved

Comment: Hi :) Thank you, but my problem has already been solved.

Comment: Okay ^_^ it's maybe helpful too for someone

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this by creating your button like so:

```
<button class="button1" onclick="Remove(this.parentElement.id)">Remove Attraction</button>
```

This way your button doesn't need an `id` and you don't need to concatenate "Attraction" to the passed id inside your Javascript function.

Comment: but the div id will be a number. And afaik this is still not a valid html

Comment: @LelioFaieta No, the div id is "Attraction" + a number suffix.

Comment: Yes but the button id seems to be a number. I changed that yet it still doesnt work unfortunately